# Is it safe to use a proxy server within psiphon?

Tags: proxy

I have to use VPN services to access many websites, and among them, I use Psiphon the most. However, now it is hard to even access Psiphon. So I have to use a proxy server to connect to Psiphon. The question is, is it as safe as if I was using Psiphon without a proxy server? Is data available to those who access to the proxy server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand, Psiphon uses an encrypted tunnel (VPN like) for communication. That means if you first send data to proxy that then sends it to Psiphon, all the data going through the proxy is encrypted. The proxy owner can see when and how much you use it, but he does not see any more then your ISP already would. He can't see any content specifically.